# Select according to a function af a line of a table

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have the table

```
t= {{1, 2, 11}, {0, 2, 11}, {2, 1, 11}}
```

How to `Select` or to `Pick` the first element of the list such that its sum be 14.

For instance, I don't know how to make reference to the element of the list.

```
Select[t,#== 14,1]
```

Doesn't work?

Comment: If `Select[{{1, 2, 11}, {0, 2, 11}, {2, 1, 11}}, Total[#] == 14 &, 1]` is the answer then my claim is that you have not paid attention to documentation examples, your code does not even have `&`.

Comment: @Kuba the only other interpretation I can think of is `Select[{{1, 2, 11}, {0, 2, 11}, {2, 1, 11}}, Total[#] == 14 &][[;;,1]]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP yep, also reasonable

Comment: Thanks to both, I Have only forget to typeset the & in the question, but this morning nearly the same command that the one proposed by Kuba has not worked. I am not able to rework my mistake.

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=89&v=1777

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = {{0, 2, 11}, {1, 2, 11}, {2, 1, 11}};

SelectFirst[list, Total@# == 14 &]
```

> {1, 2, 11}

```
First @ Pick[list, Total /@ list, 14]
```

> {1, 2, 11}

```
GroupBy[list, Total][14] // First
```

> {1, 2, 11}

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    t = {{1, 2, 11}, {0, 2, 11}, {2, 1, 11}};
    Cases[t, x_ /; Total[x] == 14] // First

(*  {1, 2, 11}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
t = {{1, 2, 11}, {0, 2, 11}, {2, 1, 11}};
Extract[t, FirstPosition[Plus @@@ t, 14]]

(*  {1, 2, 11}  *)
```